Why does the == operator not work with float?
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

    float a=5.1;
    printf("%f",  a==5.1);
    return 0;

}

== is a relational operator ... why is it not working with float values...can anyone please rectify my mistake....when i am using integer values then it is giving correct answer but not with float values...why?

printf("%f", a==5.1); -> printf("%d", a==5.1);. Didn't you get any compiler warnings?

Enable your compiler warnings.

"What is the mistake" --> not enabling all compilers warnings.  Save time and enable them all. I see 3 other mistakes and a well enabled compiler will tell you.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I only see one blatant mistake. What are the two other ones? -Wall and -Wextra only show one warning. https://godbolt.org/z/5P7xWKdbd

@Jabberwocky Try -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion  -Wfloat-equal -fmessage-length=0 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wformat=2 -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Werror=stringop-truncation

This question is similar to: Is floating-point math broken?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@the it's not quite a dupe, because one of the issues here is using %f instead of %d for printing an int value.

@thebusybee: Please do not promiscuously mark floating-point questions as duplicates of that one. That question generally speaks to the fact that floating-point operations include rounding errors, but it does not answer specific questions such as how languages handle types, literal constants, conversions, and so on. Merely having the same general subject matter does not make a question a duplicate.

There are two problems in your code.
You use the %f format specifier for printing an integer. Replace %f with %d in printf.
The other problem is more subtle: the type of 5.1 is double and not float. float a=5.1 assigns a double value to a float variable, which is not actually wrong. The problem occurs in a==5.1 where you compare actually a float to a double hence the result may not be equal.
Corrected code:
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

    float a = 5.1f;
    printf("%d",  a == 5.1f);
    return 0;
}

By appending f to 5.1 you tell the compiler that you actually want 5.1 be a float instead of a double and hence the comparision will be equal.

Useful answer, +1. A side note: comparing floating point values to exact numbers (without tolerance) is not a good practice (although here it is OK because the variable is assigned with exactly the same number).

??? Why is 5.1 not float? Wouldn't it make more sense having two values, 5.1f (float) and 5.1d (double) and let 5.1 be the one or the other, depending on the resulting variable (like double d=5.1 (here it's 5.1d) and float f=5.1 (here it's 5.1f))?

@Dominique the type of an expression is usually not dependant on what you assign it into.

@Dominique That's how Rust works, so the idea works. C could in principle work like that, but it doesn't, it just doesn't have this feature (and is unlikely to get it at this point).

@wohlstad: really? I thought that the result of bool b=1;  resulted in b having true as a value, so a variable's value can change according to its type.

@Dominique 1 is converted into bool when assigned to bool b. But so it 5.1 (double) when it is assigned into the float. It does not change the type of 1 or 5.1 by itself (at least in C which is the subject here).

@Dominique one value can be converted if needed for an assignment. Here, 5.1 gets shortened to 5.1f. But in a == 5.1 the right side is not shortened. Instead the smaller side is converted to larger side. But what was lost during assignment, cannot be recovered here.

@Dominique 6.5.16.1.2 (and nearby paragraphs) in the C standard explains assignment.

@Gerhardh , should you care to delve into the deep: "Here, 5.1 gets shortened to 5.1f" --> Note there are 2 conversions going on, not 1. Sometimes float x = source_code; is not the same as float x = source_code_with_an_appended_f;.

@chux-ReinstateMonica thanks for the link. I guess I need more coffee to dig into that level of details. ;)

a == 5.1f is also not guaranteed to succeed on an implementation where FLT_EVAL_METHOD is not 0. In that case the compiler may use a higher precision for the literal than its type would allow. That commonly happens e.g. in 32bit x86 implementations (https://godbolt.org/z/oz6dajqjY). You need to write (float)5.1 to actually force the rounding to float precision. And even then, you need to be careful about your compiler not behaving standard-conforming, as e.g. GCC is without -std=cXX or -fexcess-precision=standard flags. (That's all in addition to double-rounding issues.)

@jabberwocky...i understood second point..but i didn't understand first one...like I think we use %f for printing real numbers na ..and to print integers we need %d ...then why we used %d here? As 5.1 is not an integer

@DIVYAYADAV with %f printf expects a double but the result of a comparison with ==  (and other relational operators) is an int.

5.1 is a double (53 significant bits in IEEE double precision). In binary it will be something like
101.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110

When you convert that to float (24 significant bits in IEEE single precision) you get something like
101.000110011001100110011

And when you convert that float back to double you get something like
101.00011001100110011001100000000000000000000000000000 <== double to float to double
101.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110 <== original double

These two numbers are definitely not equal!
(*) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754
